# Subsetting a data frame by rows for 2 different parameters in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I want to filter a large data frame for getting a subset of the data where two different specifications in the same column are operated. I've tried something like this:

```
data[data$age=="ad" & data$age=="juv",]
```

I want to receive only that rows, where the age is ad (adult) **AND ALSO** juv (juvenile) for special cases.

Comment: What's the issue? Might be worth checking if the columns are `character`.

Comment: you can use the subset 

`vec=c("ad","juv")
subset(data,age %in% vec)`

Comment: The column is now defined as character, but I only get a table with the NAs of the data set! Maybe I have to add that it exists one column with numbers and a few numbers exists several times (one time for "ad" and other times for "juv"). I want to receive only the rows with this numbers.

Comment: Kindly share the sample dataset. Specially for `data$age`

Comment: The data set is much too long, but in the column 'age' there are only the two characters "ad" and "juv". I want to receive the rows, where one number of the other column called 'PIT 'has two entries, BOTH ad and juv. I hope this explanation is helpful!